# Using Shapeless to implement an (HList of Function, Input) => Tuple typeclass

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've got some existing code along the lines of

```
trait Field[T]
object Fields {
  case object Id extends Field[Int]
  case object Name extends Field[String]
  // ... and so on
}

// basically just a Map[Field[_], Any]
class QueryResultData {
  def apply[T](field: Field[T]): T
}

def query(fields: Set[Field]): QueryMonad[QueryResultData]
```

So for example if I want to query the Id and Name data, I need to do something like:

```
val idsAndNames = for {
  results <- query(Set(Fields.Id, Fields.Name))
} yield {
  val id = results(Fields.Id)
  val name = results(Fields.Name)
  (id, name)
}
```

Having to manually extract each field's result is tedious, especially when the query includes more fields. What I'd like to be able to do is:

```
val idsAndNames: QueryMonad[(Int, String)] = query(Fields.Id -> Fields.Name)
```

And have some kind of typeclass handle the `val id = ...` part and reconstruct the tuple for me, e.g.

```
def query[Fields <: HList, Tuple](fields: Fields)
  (implicit extractor: Extractor[Fields, T])
  : QueryMonad[T]
```

**How can I implement the `Extractor` typeclass so that I don't have to manually extract results?**

---

**What I've Tried**

I figured this was a job for [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), as the `query` method is meant to work on any number of fields, and is expected to give me back an appropriate tuple.

I defined a `FieldExtractor` type:

```
class FieldExtractor[T](field: Field[T]) {
  def apply(results: QueryResultData): T = results(field)
}
```

and a polymorphic function for Field to FieldExtractor:

```
object makeFieldExtractor extends (Field ~> FieldExtractor) {
  def apply[T](field: Field[T]) = new FieldExtractor[T]
}
```

and for simplicity's sake I'll start by dealing with HLists instead of Tuples:

```
val someFields = Fields.Id :: Fields.Name :: Fields.OtherStuff :: HNil
```

I tried using my `makeFieldExtractor` to convert `someFields` into `someFieldExtractors`. This is where I started running into trouble.

```
val someFieldExtractors = someFields.map(makeFieldExtractor)
```

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[MakeFieldExtractor.type,shapeless.::[Fields.Id.type,shapeless.::[Fields.Name.type,shapeless.::[Fields.OtherStuff.type,shapeless.HNil]]]]

It seems like the problem is that it's seeing types like `Fields.Id.type` when it probably should be seeing `Field[Int]`. If I explicitly specify the field types for `someFields`, the map works, but I don't want client code to have to do that. The compiler should do that for me. And let's assume I can't just change the `Id`/`Name` definitions to a `val` instead of a `case object`.

I found https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/klist.scala but didn't manage to make any successful use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would done it.

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
import Field._

trait Field[A]
object Field {
  case object IntField extends Field[Int]
  case object StringField extends Field[String]
  // Here is a little trick to proof that for any T that
  // happened to be a subclass of Field[A] the Out is A
  implicit def fieldExtractor[T, A]
  (implicit ev: T <:< Field[A]): Extractor.Aux[T, A] =
    new Extractor[T] {
      override type Out = A
    }
}

// The extractor for A
trait Extractor[A] {
  type Out // Produces result of type Out
}

object Extractor {
  // The Aux pattern http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html
  type Aux[A, Out0] = Extractor[A] {
    type Out = Out0
  }

  // Proof that Out for HNil is HNil
  implicit val hnilExtractor: Aux[HNil, HNil] = 
    new Extractor[HNil] {
      override type Out = HNil
    }

  // Proof that Out for T :: H is hlist of extractor result for H and T
  implicit def hconsExtractor[H, HO, T <: HList, TO <: HList]
  (implicit H: Aux[H, HO], T: Aux[T, TO]): Aux[H :: T, HO :: TO] =
    new Extractor[H :: T] {
      override type Out = HO :: TO
    }
}

type QueryMonad[A] = A

// Use dependent type Out as a result
def query[Fields](fields: Fields)(implicit extractor: Extractor[Fields]): QueryMonad[extractor.Out] = ???


val result = query(IntField :: StringField :: HNil)
```

Comment: Thanks! The approach of inductively buliding the `Extractor` instances worked out well

Comment: @Dylan do you have simple code that replaces `???` in the `query` method? I can't come up with anything that compiles and I'd like to try out your example.